# Why does text goes outside of my speech bubble?

Tags: html, css

I have build a basic chat program.

Everytime a user sends a message, the message is displayed like a speech bubble. The problem however, is that if the user writes a long text the bubble does not expand in height. Instead the text goes outside the bubble.

```css
    .blue {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      margin-top: 12px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #31abb2;
      text-align: left;
      height: auto;
      padding: 6px;
      max-width: 50%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      right: 20px;
      display: block;
      float: right;
      clear: both;
    }

    .blue:after {
      content: '';
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 5px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-left: 10px solid #31abb2;
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      right: -20px;
    }
```

```css
.chat {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

The bubbles get added to this:

```html
<div data-role="main" id="columnForChatWindow">
        <div class="chat" id="chat">
           <!--Messages and updates are displayed here-->
          </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some html as well?

Comment: your html? show it

Comment: Show the HTML please

Comment: The problem does not seem to be in the HTML : while testing it, all seems OK (See https://jsfiddle.net/rb8oeffh/). I'm guessing another CSS rule interferes with the display.

Comment: The html for the bubble only consists of <div class="blue">' + message.body + '</div>

Comment: @MarcBrillault, could it be the div the bubbles are added to that causes the problem?

Comment: @JonasSH no, see my example, I've used a div.blue and it works. Can you paste an HTML + CSS example where is doesn't work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following will do the trick:

```
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
```

The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

```css
.blue {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #31abb2;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.blue:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #31abb2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="blue">21321123</span>

<span class="blue">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</span>



<span class="blue">12312312312312312123123123123123121231231231231231212312312312312312123123123123123121231231231231231212312312312312312</span>
```

Comment: With this code the text no longer goes outside the bubble.. However, it still doesn't expand in height

Comment: @JonasSH ok try use `white-space: wrap !important;` you might get overwrite somewhere so use !important

Comment: would an image of the text example be okay?

Comment: @JonasSH yes, img ok

Comment: @JonasSH sorry my bad use white-space: normal !important;

Comment: upvote for investigating a new "Lorem Ipsum" with the definition of "Lorem Ipsum"

Comment: @JonasSH ok use `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: @JonasSH Cool =D

Comment: @JonasSH oh try replace the word-break with `word-wrap: break-word;` might be better, this one only break the word that is too long to fit, otherwise it will just wrap each word to fit.